# Proof about converging absolutely with respect to equivalent norm

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, absolute-convergence

If series converges absolutely with respect to some norm, then it also converges absolutely with respect to any kind of equivalent norm.

I need to prove this assertion, but I have no idea from where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\|\cdot \|_1$ and $\|\cdot \|_2$ be equivalent norms on a normed vector space $S.$ That is, the norms generate the same topology. Then the norms are uniformly equivalent : There exist positive $A, B$ such that for all $v\in S$ we have $A\|v\|_1\leq \|v\|_2\leq B\|v\|_1$.

Otherwise, with $(i,j)=(1,2)$ or $(i,j)=(2,1) ,$ there exists $T=\{v_n\}_{n\in N}\subset S$ with $\|v_n\|_i=1$ and $\|v_n\|_j<1/n$ for each $n\in N.$   With respect to the $j$-norm, the vector $0$ belongs to $\overline T,$ but with respect to the $i$-norm, $0\not \in \overline T,$ so the norms are not equivalent.

That should be enough to solve the problem.